# Semaphores in C++ /linux

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, semaphore

How can I increment the semaphore based on a function output count in a thread safe manner with multiple consumers?

Basically how do I increment the sem_post(&semValue)  by an amount that can change during run time and how do I decrements the semwait(&semValue) by a runtime amount?

Comment: With POSIX semaphores you can only inc/dec by a value of `1`. If System V semaphores are available you can use them to inc/dec by arbitrary values. Take a look at `semget(2)/semop(2)`